# How to print user input data on screen

Tags: html, output, storage, user-input

When the user inputs data into each box and then clicks submit, how would I have that information stored into some memory so it can be outputted onto the screen. It is ok if the page is refreshed and all data is lost. As long as it is possible to output the data while on the page. I was told html5 could do this without the need of the page refreshing.

Basically, I want the user to input a Job ID, a Date and a description. The user then clicks submit. the data is then outputted onto the table.

My Code is probably not worth much here, I just have it up so people know where I'm standing.
And I understand it's not as simple as just writing a bit of code. I just need someone to give me a bit of direction, where exactly I should start and how I should approach this. I've searched the internet but I couldn't find what I needed. I'd like the simplest way to output the user input onto the screen. I want to try and avoid any heavy programming or any new languages for the moment but if that's not possible then let me know.
I was also told to use the 'memory' for storing. That's all the information I was given. I apologize if I haven't asked the question very technically, I've only began using HTML5.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Form table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "testing.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class = "scrollWrapper">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Job ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>


        </table>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id = "sec2">
        <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
            <p>Job ID:</p><input type="text" name="jobid"><br>
            <p>Date:</p><input type="text" name="date"><br>
            <p>Description:</p> <input type="text" name="description"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going to need a little bit of JavaScript in order for that to work. You don't need memory (since you say it doesn't matter if the data gets lost on page refresh).
HTML5 has an `<output>` element where you can output what a user inputs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Form table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "testing.css" />
    <script>
        function display(form){
            form.o_jobid.value = form.jobid.value;
            form.o_date.value = form.date.value;
            form.o_description.value = form.description.value;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="input" action="" method="get" onsubmit="return display(this);">
        <section>
            <div class = "scrollWrapper">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Job ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><output name="o_jobid" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>
                    <td><output name="o_date" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>
                    <td><output name="o_description" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>
                </tr>


            </table>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id = "sec2">

                <p>Job ID:</p><input type="text" name="jobid"><br>
                <p>Date:</p><input type="text" name="date"><br>
                <p>Description:</p> <input type="text" name="description"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </section>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have placed the `form` outside of the `sections` in order for the `output` elements to work and added a `display` function in the forms `onsubmit` method.
The `display` function basically adds the users input in the corresponding output elements. (`return false`) is only so the form doens't actually submit it's data to the browser.

For browser support, the `output` element is supported by most modern browser (Chrome 13+, Firefox 6+, IE10+).
If you need support for a wider range you need to change the `display` function and the `output` elements.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. It was fairly straightforward and I know where I have to look into to persist in making my site now. I'm also delighted to know that it works on those three modern browsers. Thanks a million.